# Why is the DaysiUI library connected twice when starting the nuxt v3 project?

Tags: nuxt3, daisyui

When i run the Nuxt v3 project (npm run dev) DaysiUI (tailwind css library) connected twice. Why?

npm run dev output
[npm run dev output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NhJC.png)

nuxt.config.ts

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: [
    '~/assets/css/main.css',
    '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css',
    'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css',
    'tippy.js/themes/light-border.css'
  ],
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },
});
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./components/**/*.{js,vue,ts}",
    "./layouts/**/*.vue",
    "./pages/**/*.vue",
    "./plugins/**/*.{js,ts}",
    "./nuxt.config.{js,ts}",
    "./app.vue",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  darkMode: 'media',
  plugins: [
    require("daisyui")
  ],
}
```

Expecting DaysiUI connected once.